# CSS: Using first-of-type only on certain occurrences of a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how to indicate that a 'first-of-type' should only occur on certain occurrences of a div. For example, let's say I have a class ".maintext" and that in certain circumstances I would like the first paragraph to have a dropcap and in other circumstances not.

I generally do something like:

```
.maintext { font, border, etc }
.maintext p:first-of-type:first-letter { css for the dropcap }
```

But with this, each time I use `<div class='maintext'>` it calls the dropcap. How can I indicate in the HTML that sometimes I would like the dropcap and other times not, so I can keep things DRY?

My general HTML for this would be like:

```
<div class="maintext>
<p>some text</p>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of circumstances? Depending on the **"circumstances"**, you may need javascript for that

Comment: post your HTML also

Comment: It would be something I could hardcode into the page. For example, on the "about" page I would want the maintext to have a dropcap on the first paragraph, but not on the "contact" page.

Answer (score 2):

No need to overthink. Just use a class for your paragraph tags & reuse it wherever needed regardless of its container.

```
p.hasDropCap:first-letter {
  font: bold 28px Georgia;
}
```

If you want only the first paragraph of `.maintext` to have a dropcap, go about like this:

```
.maintext p:first-child:first-letter {
  font: bold 28px Georgia;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also make use of `:first-line` if you want to style the entire, well, first line.

Comment: Thanks! Although I should have been more clear and specific. I will be able to style the main div (`<div class="maintext">`) but I won't be able to style individual paragraphs because of the way the text is generated. So what I'm looking for is some way to turn off the `p:first-child:first-letter` on particular occurrences of `<div class="maintext">`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Which is why I gave you the easy option to go class based. Apply the class only to those paragraphs where you want the drop-cap & the rest would be without one.

Comment: Thanks, although the thing is, because of the way the text is generated on this site, I can't actually assign classes to individual paragraphs. That's the problem, and why I was trying to figure out a good way to accomplish this with the classes that are on the div.

Comment: What is the process with which the text is generated? Is there a way you can wrap that text with `<p class="hasDropCap"></p>` while it is being generated?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! The text is coming from a WYSIWYG field in a CMS; the user entering the text won't see any `<p>` and also isn't expected to understand any HTML/CSS or, for that matter, to have any involvement in deciding where there should be a dropcap or not. That's why I'm trying to figure out an elegant way to code the `<div>` that holds the text.

Comment: This is a case of custom & conditional styling without any means of capturing the element in question. I'm afraid, you might have to achieve the above manually.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that thought for me; I was thinking it wouldn't be easily possible -- thanks for the assistance in sorting this out!

Answer (score 1):

@Nimsrules answer is correct. I'll just add it here if you want the other way around.

```
.maintext { font, border, etc }
.maintext p:not(.nodropcap):first-of-type:first-letter { css for the dropcap }
```

HTML

```
<div class="maintext>
    <p class="nodropcap">some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```